# C# render video project from camtasia/sony vegas?

Tags: c#, video, rendering

anyone know how to render vegas/camtasia project in C# without this software? OR maybe there is someting else? I need software to create video template and then render it only in C#.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! To get helpful answers, please include the code or steps you have tried so far to solve this problem so we can help you debug or improve it.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)